# Erase USB by means of Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: usb, permissions

I got a wrong Ubuntu OS downloaded to my USB.  I want to change its permissions so I can erase the USB and get the right OS, but it won't let me. How can I force it to change those permissions?

Gparted shows unallocated space. How to format the USB drive?

Answer (score 1):

For just formatting a USB, there's no need to install any external packages.

Ubuntu 18.04 comes with Disks (`gnome-disks`) which can do basic management of drives.

You can launch it, then select the drive you want to format, click the vertical ellipsis icon (`⋮`) then `Format Disk...`.

Comment: How do I launch gnome-disks?

Comment: It should just be one of the default applications if you check the app list, if in the terminal you can just do the `gnome-disks` command. (This assumes the OS installed is Ubuntu Desktop.)

Comment: No such command.  My output: mogens@mogens-ThinkPad-T60:~$ gnome-disk

Command 'gnome-disk' not found, did you mean:

  command 'gnome-disks' from deb gnome-disk-utility

Comment: That's because you typed the command wrong, it's `gnome-disks`, not `gnome-disk`. The output of the command also suggested the correct command.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open gparted (you can install it with the command `sudo apt install gparted` if it is not installed).
2. Select your USB drive in the right upper corner, it may be `/dev/sdb`.
   [image]
3. Right click the partition in your USB drive, and format it to FAT32.
   In case it shows unallocated, select `new`
   [image]
4. Select FAT32, and leave the other option to default values.
   [image]
5. Select the checkmark to apply the operation.
   [image]
6. Close gparted, and you are done.
   [image]

Comment: I got this output:

Comment: "Comment too long by 821 characters"....

Comment: How can I select the USB?

Comment: @MogensEliasen I have added a screenshot.

Comment: I do not get the screen you show...

Comment: @MogensEliasen Did you open gparted? What do you see?

Comment: The black terminal screen asking for input.

Comment: Is there a special way of OPENING the program?

Comment: @MogensEliasen *The black terminal screen asking for input.* Did you lose your graphical interface? Please edit your question and describe the exact issue you are facing. Possibly add a screenshot.

Comment: I don't understand what you want.

Comment: Nothing happens when I install gparted

Comment: Except that I can only type a line before the system freezes

Comment: You will have to go to the menu (or activities) and type gparted. Then you need to click on its icon to open it. But I am confused because you wrote there is a black terminal screen. Can you access the desktop interface? In that case you can even install gparted from the software center.

Possibly the system did not freeze. The terminal is waiting for you to type your password and press `Enter`

Comment: I do not know how to add a screenshot

Comment: I opened gparted as you said.  The terminal is gone.

Comment: My screen looks different from the one you showed.  I cannot rightclick on anything.

Comment: Rightclicking gives the option to resize or dismount, but none of is allowed by the system.

Comment: @MogensEliasen You can upload a screenshot to imgur or a similar website, and post the link here.
You will have to select the usb drive, right click to unmount, and right click to format it.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/TiJuDOy

Comment: @MogensEliasen  1. Connect your USB drive (close gparted first). 2. Open gparted, and click here (see this https://imgur.com/a/V4IXjSj ). 3. Choose `/dev/sdb` (this is your usb drive. `/dev/sda` is your computer's HDD or SSD) . 4. Right click on the partition of the USB drive, unmount, and click format as FAT32. 5. Click on the checkmark to apply the format operation. Done

Comment: It does not work.  The device is "unallocated" and doing what you suggest gives the error "Not allowed".  Unmounting is impossible this way.,

Comment: @MogensEliasen Check the edited answer.

Comment: Please understand that I understand you. But things don;t happen as you suggest. Right-clicking on ANYTHING leads to an error message.  Unmounting this way is not possible.

Comment: @MogensEliasen What error message? Please post it. As I previously said, you don't need to unmount in case it is showing unallocated.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/uwhIREY

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/4TgJwxe

Comment: So, I can freely use the USB-stick now?

Comment: Adding the USB-stick does not even show on the computer.

Comment: @MogensEliasen It is not showing up because it does not have a partition (because it says unallocated). You need to create a new FAT32 partition. I don't know why it shows that error. I suggest you ask a friend who can format it for you.

Comment: I played with the gparted program, and I think I got the USB-stick formatted to FAT32.

Comment: The rest went as you suggested.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @MogensEliasen In case it worked, please consider accepting my answer (by clicking on the checkmark on my answer)

Comment: I don't know how to do that - I see no check marks.  But I flagged the central message, does that do it?

Comment: @MogensEliasen One has to click on this check mark to accept an answer (only do that if my answer fixed your issue). https://imgur.com/a/UyKueUe

Comment: I do not see that check mark.  But your answers helped me solve my problem.